# Angular.js change table data on button click

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

Have started coding with Angular.js in mvc and I have ran in to a problem how do you get the data in the table to change on button click from reminder to customer info lets say I the data from the info page shown when click customer and I want data from reminder table when I click reminder.I also have an issue where the search is counting the number in the database but not the number that is shown after the table is filtered threw a search.Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.Also if any one knows how to do simple pagination that would be perfect to thanks.

```
<script>
        var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);
        MyApp.controller('MyAppCtrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.Info = [
              { "date":"23/09/2014","name": "john", "detail": "sssss" },
              { "date": "27/09/2014", "name": "mary", "detail": "gggggg"  }


            ];
$scope.remind = [
                  { "date":"23/09/2014", "detail": "milk" },
                  { "date": "27/09/2014","detail": "bread"  }


                ];
        $scope.sortField = 'name';//starting sort
        $scope.reverse = true;
        });


    </script>
    <div class="container" ng-app="MyApp">
        <div class="row" style="padding-top: 60px">
            <div class="panel panel-warning">
                <div class="panel-heading">Home

                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">

                    @*  left *@
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="">

                            <div class="butLay">
                                @Html.ActionLink("Reminders", "Reminders", null, new { @class = "btn btn-warning btn-md" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="butLay">



                            @Html.ActionLink("Expected customer", "Expectedcustomer", null, new { @class = "btn btn-info btn-md" })
                        </div>

                    </div>


                    @*  Right side*@
                    <div class="pr col-md-6" ng-controller="MyAppCtrl">
                        Search:<input ng-model="query" type="text" />
                        <span class="label label-info">{{Info.length}} </span>
                        <table class="table table-striped table-hover ">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th><a href="" ng-click="sortField = 'date'; reverse = !reverse">Date</a></th>
                                    <th><a href="" ng-click="sortField = 'name'; reverse = !reverse">Name</a></th>
                                    <th><a href="" ng-click="sortField = 'detail'; reverse = !reverse">detail</a></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>


                                <tr ng-repeat="custom in Info| filter:query | orderBy:sortField:reverse">
                                    <td>{{custom.date}}</td>
                                    <td>{{custom.name}}</td>
                                    <td>{{custom.detail}}</td>              
                                </tr>                   
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        @*<ul class="pagination pagination-sm">
                            <li class="disabled"><a href="#">«</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">»</a></li>
                        @*</ul>*@


                    </div>

                </div>
                <table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped"></table>
            </div>
            @* of panel *@
        </div>
        @*of row*@
    </div>
    @* of container *@
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make 2 Tables and one has

```
ng-if="variable==false";
```

the other has

```
ng-if="variable==true";
```

Then u do a Button with

```
ng-click="myfunction(variable)"
```

and in controller u have

```
$scope.myfunction = function(variable){

    if(variable == true){
         variable = false;
    }else{
         variable = true;
    }
}
```

So when u click the variable gets set true or false and the right content is showing

To set which table should be shown defaul

```
ng-init="variable==true"
```

for example

hope this helps

Comment: so am I right in saying    $scope.myfunction = function (Reminder,Admissions) {

            if (Reminder == true) {
                Admissions = false;
            } else {
                Admissions = true;
            }
        } and <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-md" ng-click="myfunction(Admissions)">Admissions</button>, <button type="button" class=" btn btn-warning btn-md" ng-click="myfunction(Reminder)">Reminders</button> and  ng-init="Reminder==true" ng-if="Reminder==true" on one table and ng-if="Admissions==false" on the other